# What is a browser plugin that alters website contents?

Tags: browser, plugins

I'm thinking about a browser plugin that changes the text or images of websites before displaying them to the user.  I guess it's similar to a web filter, but it doesn't prevent content from getting through, just alters it.  like, e.g., Gizoogle, but built into the browser instead of being a site that you visit.

What's this called?  Browser layer?  Web interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most famous example is perhaps [Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-pt/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox. I think that such plugins do not have their own name yet, but I would say they are "web page customizers".

Comment: They use "UserScripts"

Comment: according to [Greasemonkey's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) it's called Augmented Browsing.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could call them javascript userscripts, and Greasemonkey is a popular engine for them.

Opera and Google Chrome has Greasemonkey built-in, so you do not need to install any extensions when using those browsers.

There are many Greasemonkey userscripts available at [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/), and it is not difficult to make your own.